# How do I duplicate an array in Java (including values)?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, oop, copy

I am building a card game - currently building the deck - and I was wondering how you would go about duplicating an array with the same values.
For example:

```
Card[] cards = {card.set('A', Card.spades), card.set('2', Card.spades)....};
int n = cards.length;
Card[] cardsDuplicate = new Card[2 * n]
```

I want the values of `cardsDuplicate = {card.set('A', Card.spades), card.set('2', Card.spades),card.set('A', Card.spades), card.set('2', Card.spades)};`

Basically copying whatever values were in the first part of the array and then reapplying them in the second part. I can think of ways to do it using for loops and if statements but I feel like that is extremely inefficient and long. I'm used to Python and this is my first time using Java so I may be wrong; Any advice?

Comment: Do you also need copies of the `Card` instances or is an array with the same references OK? e.g. do you consider `cards[0] == cardsDuplicate[0]` (reference equality) to be true or false?

Comment: `cards.clone()`

Answer (score 0):

try System.arraycopy().

```
System.arraycopy(cards, 0, cardsDuplicate, 0, n);
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-

Comment: This will only copy the references. It is unclear if the question is asking that or how to create copies (clones) of the objects referenced by the array elements.

Comment: Yes, youare right.  It just do Shadow copy for the elements of array.

Comment: "shallow" copy (as opposed to a deep copy). not a shadow copy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using method `copyOf()` which is coming from `Arrays`. This method can give you exactly same copy or exactly same array:

```
String[] names = new String[] {"John", "Cecille", "Mark", "Judas", "Theresa"};
/* 
   - Arrays.copyOf() method takes two params
   - 1st is the original array
   - 2 is size for your new array 
*/
String[] duplicate = Arrays.copyOf(names, names.length+1);
```